# How browser auto resize website to mobile browse?

Tags: css, browser, web, resolution, autoresize

I created a website without using mobile theme.
If i open my website in my smart phone browser, it resizing my theme.
I mean, It automatically reduce the size to my mobile browser.
For example...I already mention my text box size in my CSS code. The mobile screen pixel size is differ from desktop machine screen pixel size.

My Question is, how it reduce the screen resolution to mobile view?
please clear my doubt.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you link to your site? Or show us some of your code? It is hard to tell you what the problem is without seeing at least the code.

Comment: sorry i am just asking is the mobile browser auto scale the website to mobile view?

Comment: ...it depends on your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either there might be some media queries defined within your stylesheet like

```
@media handheld, only screen and (max-width: 1024px) 
{
    //Style goes here
}
```

Which is a style defined for screens having maximum width of 1024px.

Another possibility is, styles may be defined fully in percentage. So that the styles are changed according to the window size.

Again there might be some scripts used in your code to resize. All depends on the code that you are using. There are variety of methods which fits the view according to the screen size.

Comment: Is there any javascript required to make this happen? or just `@media` and the corresponding styles is enough for the entire site to go mobile?

Comment: No, but you must add <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> within the head tag.

Comment: According to your site layout, you have define @media styles at various widths. Style define for single media screen may not be enough.

Comment: That's it? So just, <html><head></meta><style>@media{}</style></head><body><code></body> is enough?

Comment: and that is when the javascript libraries come in picture, right/

Comment: <html><head><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"><style>@media handheld, only screen and (max-width: 1024px) 
{
    //Style goes here
}</style></head></html>

Comment: Maybe I'm doing it wrong, but this doesn't appear to work for me.

Answer (score 5):

Do you mean to resize your sites content for the handheld device? If you have a fluid layout (with % instead of pixels for widths) use:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Further reading: http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/targeting.html

Answer (score 1):

if you want scale it in browser tell it in css.And use all width in % values

eg:

```
 @media handheld, only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
 //mobile version css

  }
```